# Firebase is not getting initialized right

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

So, I wanted to include firebase into my Flutter App, it works fine for android but when I start it on my ios emulator it will always give me this error

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.
> Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.
> View the documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initialization

I have the google-service file in the right directory and I followed the tutorial and edited my main() to:

```
    Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Has anybody the same problem with IOS or did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Have you added GoogleService-Info.plist. file?

Comment: yep added the file to my directory

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So for everybody else getting this error I figured it out myself, for IOS, the line

```
  Firebase.initializeApp()
```

it needs an option:

```
Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform)
```

for that follow the instructions on this link:

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli

hope that helps anyone

Answer (score 8):

1. **Install [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) if it is not installed in your system.**
2. **Next, install the [FlutterFire CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/) or by running the following command:`dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`**. Once installed, the flutterfire command will be globally available.
3. Run `flutterfire configure` in your flutter project folder in terminal,
4. Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with,
5. Select/Insert android app id and bundle id you want to use as and when it asks you.
6. and get firebase_options.dart.
7. In main.dart file import firebase_options.dart.
8. In void main() use following code.

```
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
         if (Platform.isIOS) {
         await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
         );
           } else {
             await Firebase.initializeApp();
             }
        runApp(
        const MaterialApp(
        home: MyApp(),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: DefaultFirebaseOptions does not exist for me

Answer (score 8):

I got same problem. My Android application is working fine but when using IOS application it's throw this type of exception. you can use @Viki's answer and if its not working for you make sure you have added `GoogleServices-info.plist` file in your ios project.
If it's not solve your issue then use this code

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "your api key Found in GoogleService-info.plist",
            appId: "Your app id found in Firebase",
            messagingSenderId: "Your Sender id found in Firebase",
            projectId: "Your Project id found in Firebase"));
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
```

Comment: solved it already myself ;)

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same issue in my flutter application when run on xcode/ ios.
Here is how I solved.

1. Download GoogleService-Info.plist from firebase account
2. Add Files to Runner like below and choose GoogleService-Info.plist from download folder

[image]

3. Re-Run the project, It will work

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I haven't added the code lines according to the instructions from firebase. The simple fix is ​​to follow the instructions from the firebase doc from start to finish.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot to add await because it returns Future.

Previously:

```
Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
```

Then

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full function to copy paste.

Convert the `main` function to:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```