# Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**My code show error  Firebase has not been correctly initialized.?**

```
**Usually this means you've attempted to use a Firebase service before calling `Firebase.initializeApp`.
E/flutter (25616): 
E/flutter (25616): View the documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#initialization
E/flutter (25616):     
E/flutter (25616): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:99:9)
E/flutter (25616): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25616): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:42:31)
E/flutter (25616): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25616): #2      main (package:a_store_online_shop/main.dart:11:3)
E/flutter (
25616): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25616):
```

It is our main.dart file which in occure error code firebase has not been correctly initialized.....................................................................................................................................................?

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:a_store_online_shop/Screens/main_screen.dart';
import 'package:a_store_online_shop/Screens/on_boarding_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const SplashScreen(),
      initialRoute: SplashScreen.id,
      routes: {
        SplashScreen.id: (context) => const SplashScreen(),
        OnBoardingScreen.id: (context) => const OnBoardingScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String id = "splash-screen";

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  final store = GetStorage();
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      bool? _boarding = store.read('onBoarding');
      _boarding == null
          ? Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, OnBoardingScreen.id)
          : _boarding == true
              ? Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, MainScreen.id)
              : Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, OnBoardingScreen.id);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge, overlays: []);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.jpg"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please show code which cause error

Comment: Show your main.dart file code

Comment: Aakib have you solved this?

Comment: not yet solved this?

Comment: Hi, can you check if this link helps you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433679/firebase-is-not-getting-initialized-right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for everybody else getting this error I figured it out myself, for IOS, the line

```
Firebase.initializeApp()
```

it needs an option:

```
Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform)
```

for that follow the instructions on this link:

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli

Comment: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-firebase-flutterfire-cli/       use it solve above error

Answer (score -2):

Unintstall your app from device and reinstall, it worked for me.

Comment: Not the best approach. But this worked.

Answer (score -2):

UnIntstall your app from device and ReInstall,