# calling Firebase.initializeApp() but still receive an error stating No Firebase App has been created, ONLY when using ios simulator

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-ios

I have initialized Firebase in different ways.

1.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

2. 

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp().whenComplete(() { 
      print("completed");
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

including using FirebaseOption and adding appId, apiKey, projectId, messgingSenderId(dummy id)

3. `//Using a FutureBuilder`

atm these libraries are present:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.10.6
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.7
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.8
  firebase_database: ^9.0.6
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.2.4
```

GogleService-Info.plsit is under flutterProject>ios>Runner
added via Xcode

I'm using a mac

Podfile has platform: ios, '11.0'

printing snapshot.connectionState = waiting & done

I receive an error when trying to persist to the database
I'm using FireStore Database

when trying to persist to the database using the Andriod emulator, I do not receive an error. obj is persisted.

but when trying to persist the same obj using the ios simulator I receive this error:

```
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MethodChannelFirebase.app (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:159:5)
#1      Firebase.app (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:55:41)
#2      FirebaseFirestore.instance (package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart:27:21)
#3      _firestore (package:flutter_shopping_app_fraire/providers/products.dart:6:56)
#4      _firestore (package:flutter_shopping_app_fraire/providers/products.dart)
#5      Products.addProduct (package:flutter_shopping_app_fraire/providers/products.dart:71:5)
#6      _EditProductScreenState._saveForm (package:flutter_shopping_app_fraire/screens/edit_product_screen.dart:111:53)
#7      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
#8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#9      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
#12     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:563:9)
#13     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#15     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#16     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#17     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#18     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:439:19)
#19     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
#20     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
#21     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#22     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#23     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#24     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#28     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#29     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#30     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#32df4
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(372.7, 95.0)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(30.7, 48.0)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013455/unhandled-exception-core-not-initialized-firebase-has-not-been-correctly-init/71013642#71013642

Comment: flutterProject>ios>Runner>AppDelegate.swift looks like this: import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
      [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
  }
}

Comment: I don't know this i am using objc

Comment: i have followed all necessary implementation from documentation. i also implemented flutterfire_cli. implemented that with no issues. however it did not fix my issue. i even started a new project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed all necessary implementation from google docs. Just do the following. I've faced the same issue. Adding options fixed mine.

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly where I went wrong when implementing firebase/firestore into my flutter project(I was doing everything manually), but I got the ios simulator to connect with firestore database by registering my ios app using [FlutterFire CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/).

so instead of manually creating a new firebase project, and registering my ios and android apps through my firebase console, I installed [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/#installation) to my project, then installed [FlutterFire CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/#installation) and ran `flutterfire configure`,  You go through a couple prompts. That created my project and also registered my apps.

It was really that simple and now both of my ios and andriod can reach the database.